# Rails3 Client Side Validation Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Have been watching Ryan's excellent screencasts and on this episode (#263 client_side_validations) he says to add the following line of code in the _form.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>
```

However, if users have Devise installed they will be putting the code into the new.html.erb file where the following code is already installed at the top which creates an error:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name))     do |f| %>
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

SyntaxError in Devise/registrations#new

```
 /app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

 compile error
 /app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER,   expecting kEND
 ...tion_path(resource_name)) user, validate => do |f| @output_b...
                          ^
 app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '='
 ...ource_name)) user, validate => do |f| @output_buffer.safe_co...
                          ^
 app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end
 Extracted source (around line #4):

1: 
2: <h2>Sign Up</h2>
3: 
 4: <%= form_for  (resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) user, validate => do |f| %>
5:  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
6: 
7:   <p><%= f.label :username %><br />
```

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :validate => true, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name))     do |f| %>
```